# Creating A Row for All Possible Combinations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that as has a number of categorical items, some of which have a month, some of which don't. In order to get an accurate average, I'd like to figure out a way to create empty row values for each category for each month, and then I can fill in the remainder.

Data looks like this:

```
 skinny_month
       month  Amount                Category
0    2019-01   18.34       Rental Car & Taxi
1    2019-01    7.95               Fast Food
2    2019-01   27.63             Restaurants
3    2019-01   69.00                     Gym
4    2019-01   20.60              Air Travel

...      ...     ...                     ...

1116 2013-04   10.00             Restaurants
```

What I'd like to return is something like:

skinny_month.groupby('Category').mean()

```
                            Amount  Notes
Category                                 
ATM Fee                   2.600000    0.0
Advertising               6.486667    0.0
Air Travel              546.166250    0.0
Books                    17.631538    0.0
Business Services         9.746923    0.0
```

Except by month, so I could then calculate my actual monthly spend. the problem is that this makes it seem like I spend more on average than I actually do, because for example my total Advertising looks like this:

```
skinny_month.groupby(['Category','month']).mean()
                             Amount
Category       month               
ATM Fee        2017-10     3.000000
...            ...         ...
Advertising    2018-06    15.340000
               2018-10     9.115000
               2018-11     5.350000
```

So since there's no spending during 2017 or 2019, it should be more like 1.10 (given a total of $28 dollars spend over two years, etc), but the average is only over three months so it shows as 6.48.

I had an earlier version with proper dates and used:

```
monthly_totals = non_savings.set_index('Category').resample('M', 'sum').fillna(method='ffill')
```

which yielded

```
                                               Amount  Notes
Date       Category               Date                      
2013-02-16 Business Services      2013-02-28    65.00    0.0
           Restaurants            2013-02-28    35.00    0.0

2019-01-16 Air Travel             2019-01-31    20.60    0.0
2019-01-17 Gym                    2019-01-31    69.00    0.0
2019-01-19 Restaurants            2019-01-31    27.63    0.0
```

I feel like there should be an easy way to generate the dates between for each category but it seems like ffill won't work because it needs the proper start and end date, additionally since the data only covers 2013, 2017, 2018, and the start of 2019, forward filling it would flatten expenses too much because I don't have any records for 2014-2016 so it would make the advertising example drop down to 0.34 which also isn't right.

I've tried doing a concat call, and feel like there should be some way to do a row wise iteration but I can't figure it out. Any help welcomed.

Comment: there's probably some sort of fancy option of counting the unique months, then totaling each category and dividing it by that number....

Answer (score 1):

Look into [pd.MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) I think can probably due what you are after.

Some variation on something like this:

```
In [24]: x = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-04-01', freq='MS')

In [25]: y = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [26]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x, y])

In [27]: for ix in index:
    ...:     print(ix)
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: 
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'c')
(Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'c')
(Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'c')
(Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'a')
(Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'b')
(Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 'c')
```